# C++ default path to application change after calling GetOpenFileName

Tags: c++, winapi

In c++ when you do something like this:

```
std::ifstream file("file.dat");
```

By default, it will go to this path:

```
C:/bla/bla/appfolder/file.dat
```

where `appfolder` is the current's `.exe` folder. Which is normal. But, when I call `GetOpenFileName()` and choose for example this file:

```
C:/somefolder/somefile.txt
```

Then if I write again `std::ifstream file("file.dat");` it will go to:

```
C:/somefolder/file.dat
```

Any possible way to fix this, or I need to add the full path?

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, I didn't see that. It's actually one flag

Comment: Crazy default behavior for `GetOpenFileName()` by the way...

Comment: @rodrigo [It's historical](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101112-00/?p=12293/)

Comment: Huh.  It seems perfectly logical to me, that's what I'd expect to happen.  (But perhaps only because I already know that it does.)